# Autoformat Text with Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, text-analysis, autoformatting

I am currently working at an issue regarding optimizing the workflow of an agency.

The agency receives like 30-40 PDF/Word documents, which should be converted into Indesign-Files, which will be print in newspapers. Its always the same pattern: job adverts with a logo, the job position and some text.
Weekly the same customers send us their adverts. Our employees usually take the patterns of the existing files and copy-paste the new text.

We apply some fix formating rules like: not words overlapping across lines, distance between the job title and the first paragraph. One important thing is to keep the height as small as possible in order to reduce costs for our clients. Because we have many employees who are new, work in part-time etc. we face a huge fluctuation. therefore we want to standardize the process, in order to only do some little changes for new adverts.... I guess you know what I mean.

Do you see a possibilty to improve the process for example with NLTK? I think of training an algorithm which recognizes  the "job title", "bullet-points", logo etc. and automatically propose a formation for the text.

A colleague told me just to write a script which formates the indesign document.

What do you think? Thanks so far.

Here is a brief example:

[Example Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koL6v.png)

Comment: Interesting idea that could potentially work. It depends very strongly on how large your training set is, i.e. the collection of already formatted ads plus their original source documents. 

Also, you would have to be able to reliably identify element such as the 'job title' in the formatted ads of the training set (which, if they are well standardized, should be possible). 

However, the effort required is potentially larger than a script with a small set of heuristic rules - both approaches will probably still require review of the resulting output by a human editor.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. - Yes, I think the same way. Some heuristic rules should help a lot. But I was told, that the longer you do the formatting stuff (i.e. gaining experience over years), you get an idea "what looks good" and what is rather ugly. Usually the older employees see immediately which adverts is fine and which is not. Because we have like thousands of already published adverts, which fulfill certain styling standards, I was thinking of using that knowledge from the past.

Comment: The problem in this connection is, that an algorithm should be able to change the distance between words (for example to prohibit that words jump in the next line), find the right distance between logo and paragraph etc.

Comment: Re using knowledge from the past: You are right, and your idea has merit. As a project manager, I would be wary of the risks involved, i.e. the resources required for tweaking the machine learning and curating the training set. At the end of the day, it comes down to the risk/benefit analysis. Technically, it should be feasible.